# XRDP-type server for use on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, remote-desktop, multiple-users

I did some searching myself, but couldn't find anything.

What I would like be able to do is to connect to Windows 10 from the latest Ubuntu via RDP or something similar, without interrupting the current session on the physical device.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want VNC. Much like remote desktop, but allows multiple users to see the same desktop as once, among other things. Vnc is available for Mac, linux, and windows.

Google tightvnc or ultravnc, should get you where you want to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I am looking for is the ability to have multiple desktops at once, allowing for multiple clients to use the same computer separately via a VNC connection.

Comment: That, unfortunately  is a limitation of the windows operating system. You might have a look at [rdpwrap](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/) as a possible solution, which does seem to offer what you are looking for. It isn't clear, however, if this violates your license agreement with Microsoft. It's a bit of a hack.